# Sorting rich:dataTable with second value in a column

Tags: sorting, jsf, datatable, richfaces

I have a rich dataTable that has a column which contains the full name of a person (Last name, first Name). I currently have the table so that the columns can be sorted based on the last name of the person. However I want it so that if the last names are equal it will then sort by the first names next. Is this possible? How can I do it?

```
<rich:column sortBy="#{list.lastName}">
   <h:outputLabel value="#{list.lastName} #{list.firstName}"/> 
</rich:column>
```

Example:

If the names were (B Smith and A Smith)

Should be sorted:

Smith A

Smith B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That isn't possible with `<rich:dataTable>`.

You'd better add a (transient) getter which returns the "full name":

```
@Transient // Only if it's a JPA entity.
public String getFullName() { 
    return lastName + " " + firstName;
}
```

And then use it in sorting:

```
<rich:column sortBy="#{list.fullName}">
```